# Hosting a socks server with ssh?

Tags: server, ssh, proxy

So I was using this command.

```
ssh -N -D 0.0.0.0:1080 localhost
```

It let me use my remote server as a socks proxy. However few days later I received an abuse report from my data center. Apparently someone was using this to send spam.

```
"Re: [#285*****] [SpamCop (192.***.***.***) id:6587******]*****SPAM***** please #### me tonite"
```

So How do I alter this command to only work with my home ip?

Comment: Which machine runs the SOCKS proxy, which machine is the proxy exit point and how are they connected? How do you authenticate yourself to the SSH server? Why don't you bind the SOCKS server to `localhost` instead of `0.0.0.0`? Did you read what the SSH manual says about the `-D` switch?

Comment: well the server is hosting the proxy, my personal computer would connect to it. I would plug it in as a socks proxy in my google chrome. "Why don't you bind the SOCKS server to localhost instead of 0.0.0.0?" well for one I don't understand these things, and I found an example where it was using 0.0.0.0

Comment: Alright. That leaves: 1) How do you authenticate yourself to the SSH server? 2) Did you read what the [SSH manual](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/ssh.1.html) says about the `-D` switch – especially the last 2 sentences?